# geopandas pairwise spatial operation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, geopandas

I need to do a pairwise-contains operation between two geodataframes. `geo_listings` contains Point geometries and `geo_listings_buffer` contains Polygon geometries corresponding to the results of running `buffer` on the first dataframe.

The `contains` function return a Series after doing an elementwise operation. I want a square matrix returned instead.

I have this code so far which works but is **very** slow:

```py
pair_contains = np.zeros((geo_listings.shape[0],geo_listings.shape[0]))
for i, row in geo_listings.iterrows():
    pair_contains[i,:] = geo_listings_buffer.contains(row['geometry'])
```

I have about 8000 rows and this code takes a good 8-9 minutes to run.

Anything to improve this would be helpful.